# Issue on reading a CSV file into FME through a startup python script

Tags: csv, python-2.7

The python script is (python 2.7) :

```
import urllib
mysock = urllib.urlopen("........")
outcsv = mysock.read()
oFile = open("c:\\temp\\example.csv",'wb')
oFile.write(outcsv)
oFile.close
```

The problem with this script is that when I run it I do not get the right rows count of the csv file.

To explain the script a bit better, with this startup python script I am calling a csv file in internet. Then I just want the script to save it in my C drive. After that a reader in FME will read to start another process.

For the moment I do it manually (copy and paste my link into a browser, recuperate the csv file and save it to the right place in my C drive) without using this script and I am getting the right numbers of entries.

I do not understand why I am getting different numbers of rows doing it manually and automatically? Does somebody have an idea?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the file that your python script writes to your disk? This might at least show you why there is a difference. I don't think this has anything to do with FME.

In FME2013 you can directly use the reader to access a web-based source dataset. This works for any file-based format and even zipped data. So you don't need to use the python-script to download the file before.